# Media-Query for Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

i need a media query for Galaxy S6. The technical specification says, that the display has a ressolution of 2560 x 1440 pixel and the pixel-ratio is 4.

So i found a lot of queries using this data. this per example:
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 4) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 4)
  and (orientation: portrait)  {

But it does not work on my S6. Now i implemented some debug-messages using JavaScript (screen-width and screen-height) and this messages are showing my a screen-ressolution of 412 x 732 pixels.

Now I'm really confused. Where comes this difference from? And is this a general problem, that can occur on all other devices too?

Anyone knows something about this or has a reference with reliable informations for the most usual devices?

Comment: I am unclear as to what outcome you are expecting from this question

Comment: I hope for an explanation, why this problem occurs. It may help me to understand the problem and find a solution, that works for me.

Comment: @Ken White  ist not a duplicated post, because the solution in the suggested post is not working. This post was the basic for the query i used.

Comment: No one can explain why *it does not work* for you, because you've shown us nothing at all about what you're trying to do. The media-query for the S6 is shown in that linked post.

Comment: and it is not working because the device is using a different ressolution, when i read it out with javascript, as i wrote. what should i show you more?